# Django: How do I get the number of elements returned in a database call?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, size

This seems to me like a very simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

All I need to do is determine the number of objects returned by a database query.

The specific circumstance is this: I have a model named Student. This model has a ManyToManyField member named courses_current, which relates to a table of Course models. When I pass my Student instance to a template, I want to be able to do something like the following (the syntax may not be exact, but you'll get the basic idea):

```
<div id="classes">
{% if student.classes_current.all.size == 0 %}
    <h1> HEY! YOU AREN'T TAKING ANY CLASSES! REGISTER NOW!
{% else %}
    Here are your courses:
    <!-- ... -->
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Now, I'm fairly certain that `X_set.all.size` is not a real thing. In the `manage.py` shell I can just use `len(student.classes_current.all())`, but I don't know of any way to use built-in functions, and "dictionary-like objects" don't have `.size()` functions, so I'm at a loss. I'm sure there's a very simple solution (or at least I hope there is), but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[{{ student.classes_current.all.count }}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) but be warned that it doesn't fetch the objects so you will need to do a separate query if you want to loop over them.

Comment: Yeeeeeep. I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need loop over the classes `for` tag has way to get what you need.

```
{% for cl in student.current_classes.all %}
    {{ cl }}
{% empty %}
    <h1>Hey! ...</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for-empty

Comment: Yeah, I knew that one already. I just wanted to be able to print an appropriate message in the case that the list was empty. Thanks though.